# Compiling external .h and .c files together

Tags: c

We have to make a project that is required to be split into parts. We were asked to create a .c file that contains the functions that we have written during classes. And we were also asked to create a .h file for the prototypes.

I did all that, and it works fine on my computer. However, we sent the .exe file, the .h prototype and the .c function files, with the main.c file, and the teacher sent it back, saying that the code won't compile.

Contents of main.c:

```
...
#include "functions.c"
#include "function_header.h"
...
```

Contents of functions.c:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) 
{
  int c,i;
  for(i = 0; i < lim && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF; i++)
    s[i] = c;
    s[i] = '\0'; // tömb lezárasa
    while(c != '\n' && c!=EOF)
      c=getchar(); // puffer ürítése
    return i;
}
```

Contents of function_header.h:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim);
```

I don't have the slightest clue why his code won't compile. Obviously, when you open up a brand new project, and copy that code in the main.c, you won't be able to use the code in .c and .h because it's included in a different folder. So what could be the problem?

Comment: You probably don't want `#include "functions.c"` in `main.c`.

Comment: Why can't you have *several* [compilation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation_unit), e.g. building your program using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) so linking several object files? Notice that `#include`-ing a `.c` file is bad taste.

Comment: But if I take out the .c include, it won't compile. Do I have to include the .c in the .h?

Comment: BTW, `getline` is a standard POSIX function. See [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). So I suggest to name your function differently.

Comment: No, dont `#include "functions.c"`, but you probably should have some `Makefile` and build your program with `make`. Details are implementation specific: what compiler, what operating system, what compilation commands are you using?

Comment: You should include the header, not the source file. Your teacher is compiling "functions.c" and "main.c" separately and linking them together. You should do the same (you've covered this process in class). If you're using gcc, `gcc functions.c main.c` is what you're expected to get working. (Right now, linking fails because of multiple definitions.)

Comment: 1) never #include a '.c' file rather, have a separate compile step for each .c file and a separate link step to link the object files into the executable.  2) the #Include of the header file `functions.h` must be in both the functions.c and the main.c files.  It cannot be after the functions as the compiler will not know the prototypes for the functions so will a) output 'implicit declaration' warnings and (probably) produce the incorrect code.

Answer (score 2):

A written in the comments you should not include `.c` source files into other source files. It's a good idea to name the `.c` and the corresponding `.h` file the same way (e.g. `functions.c` and `functions.h`)

Do it this way:

main.c:

```
...
#include "functions.h"
...
```

functions.c:

```
#include "functions.h"
...
```

functions.h:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim);
```

Then compile it (e.g. with `gcc`):

```
gcc main.c functions.c
```

And there are other things to mention when it comes to work with header files: [Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: But if I do this I get an error. If I write #include "functions.c" in functions.h it's fine, but I don't know if that's the correct way.

Comment: What error do you get? This is the correct way of doing it, if you are getting errors, resolve those errors, don't do it in another way.

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _getline referenced in function _main 

and 
LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: May you put your whole solution and Upload it somewhere and send the link.

Comment: So this is a linker error: you missed to compile functions.c or missed to add it for the linker. Is it VisualStudio?

Comment: My VS experience is faded away, but what I see from you project file you have to add fuggvenyek.c to your project ( Project Panel -> Add Existing item -> choose your c file)